# OpenSSL not installing with relative path

Tags: makefile, openssl

I am trying to install OpenSSL version `OpenSSL_1_1_0f` from source to a vendored directory as I need to statically link to it. I have read the Compilation and Installation page to figure out which flags for `./config` I need to pass in order to install it with a relative path.

Here is my installation script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VENDOR_DIR="vendor"
VENDOR_LIB=$VENDOR_DIR/lib

mkdir -p $VENDOR_LIB

# OpenSSL library info.
OPENSSL_BRANCH="OpenSSL_1_1_0f"
OPENSSL_SOURCE="openssl-source"

echo "installing openssl"
git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git $VENDOR_DIR/$OPENSSL_SOURCE -b $OPENSSL_BRANCH

pushd $VENDOR_DIR/$OPENSSL_SOURCE
./config --prefix=$VENDOR_LIB --openssldir=$VENDOR_LIB -O3
make
make test
make install
```

OpenSSL is installing to the default location of `/usr`, not under `$VENDOR_LIB`, which is where I need it to be installed. What flag combination do I need to pass to the `./config` script in order to set the target installation directory?

Answer (score 1):

just try `--prefix=$(pwd)/$VENDOR_DIR` if you want to install openssl to a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

If I try just your config line I get this:

```
$ ./config --prefix=vendor/lib --openssldir=vendor/lib -O3
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
Configuring for linux-x86_64
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.0g-dev (0x10100070L)
Directory given with --prefix MUST be absolute
```

So try giving the absolute pathnames rather than relative ones.